# What's the role of the `query` that's passed to `createPaginationContainer` in Relay Modern?

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

I've got a question about the [`PaginationContainer`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/pagination-container.html) API in Relay Modern.

When using `createPaginationContainer`, we're passing it a configuration object that also contains a `query` (as is the case in the [official example](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/pagination-container.html#example)).

I was wondering why we have to do that seen that there still is a `QueryRenderer` on the top-level that could take care of building query at the root of the hierarchy. Couldn't we just omit this second query or what's the reason that we have to include it?

I also noticed that the root query that's passed to the `QueryRenderer` also needs to have the `first` and `after` arguments to enable pagination. So, it seems like the `QueryRenderer` is still responsible to compose this query, so what's the role of the additional one that's passed to `createPaginationContainer`?